# Parsing block in file to Python list without newlines

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

**I have** a particular block of stuff in a general file of many contents which is arbitrarily long, can contain any character, begins each line with a blank space and has the form in some text file:

```
 1\1\GINC-NODE9999\Scan\...
 ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
 ... ... ... ... ...\HF=-568
 .8880019,-568.2343213, -568
 .2343432, ... , -586.328492
 1\RMSD=...
```

**I'm interested in** the particular sequence which lies between `\HF=` and `\RMSD=`.  **I want to put these numbers into a Python list.** This sequence is simply a series of numbers that are comma separated, **however**, these numbers can roll over onto a second line.  ALSO, `\HF=` and `\RMSD` may be broken by rolling over onto a newline.

**Current Efforts**

I currently have the following:

```
    with open(infile) as data:
        d1 = []
        start = '\\HF'     
        end = 'RMSD'
        should_append = False
        for line in data:
            if start in line:
                data = line[len(start):]
                d1.append(data)
                should_append=True
            elif end in line:
                should_append = False
                break
            elif should_append:
                d1.append(line)
```

which spits out the following list

```
['.6184082129,7.5129238742\\\\Version=EM64L-G09RevC.01\\
State=1-A\\HF=-568\n', ' .8880019,-568.8879907,-568.8879686,
-568.887937,-\n']
```

**The problem is** not only do I have newlines throughout, I'm also keeping more data than I should.  Furthermore, numbers that roll over onto other lines are given their own placement in the list.  I need it to look like

```
['-568.8880019', '-568.8879907', ... ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multline non-greedy regular expression can be used to extract text that lies between \HF= and \RMSD=. Once the text is extracted it should be trivially easy to tokenize into constituent numbers

```
import re
import os
pattern = r'''\HF=(.*?)\RMSD='''
pat = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)
for number in pat.finditer(open('file.txt').read()):
    print number.group(1).replace(os.linesep, '').replace(' ', '').strip(r'''\\''')
... 
-568 .8880019,-568.2343213, -568 .2343432, ... , -586.328492 1\
```

Comment: Your solution left whitespaces and a `\\\` in the list.  I was able to eliminate these by using strip("\\") and then replace(' ','').  Other than that your solution worked.  Many thanks. (If you put these two things into your example I'll green-check it :)

Comment: This code really works. But, it can be a memory and CPU outspending, considering protocol analysis. Each function call (i.e.: group, replace) will produce a new string in memory, and each further call (i.e.: replace, strip) will reprocess this intermediate string.

Comment: @apast. You are right. The largest memory consumption will likely arise from the `read` call that loads the entire file into memory. In practice, this may or may not be a concern depending on the hardware situation.

Comment: I'm not talking about file reading, considering that it only will determine input for algorithm. I'm considering the line 'print number.group(1).replace(os.linesep, '').replace(' ', '').strip(r'''\\''')'. May I edit the post and you confirm if it's fine?

Comment: @apast, the point i was trying to make is that with a large file memory conservation benefits from optimizing the string replace calls will likely pale into insignificance compared with memory usage from the `read` call. Additionally, the emphasis with Python solutions is usually on readability and I would not go ahead and optimize to the detriment of readability unless a solid case exists.

Answer (score 1):

for a fast solution, you can implement a naive string concatenation based on regular expressions.

I implemented a short solution for your data format.

```
import re

def naiveDecimalExtractor(data):
    p = re.compile("(-?\d+)[\n\s]*(\d+\.\d+)[\n\s]*(\d+)")
    brokenNumbers = p.findall(data)

    return ["".join(n) for n in brokenNumbers]

data = """
1\1\GINC-NODE9999\Scan\...
 ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
 ... ... ... ... ...\HF=-568
 .8880019,-568.2343213, -568
 .2343432, ... , -586.328492
 1\RMSD=...
"""

print naiveDecimalExtractor(data)
```

Regards,

And Past

Comment: This could be improved with [a list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw), or alternatively, make it a generator and `yield` each part.

Comment: Really! Lattyware, I need to practice more python iterations over collections and learn by experience. I will update answer for comprehension. It's really more clear. Thanks!
p.s.: I'll not reduce all code to one line just for code readability.

Comment: +1, and indeed, it's always tempting to try and one-line everything, but when it makes lines really long and hurts readability, it's a bad idea. This is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to join everything in one line:

```
with open(infile) as data:
    joined = ''.join(data.read().splitlines())
```

And then parse that without worrying about newlines.

If your file is really large you may want to consider another approach to avoid having it all in memory.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
# open the file to read
f = open("test.txt")

# read the whole file, then concatenate the list as one big string (str)
str = " ".join(f.readlines())

# get the substring between \HF= and \RMDS, then remove any '\', 'n', or ' '
values = str[str.find("\HF=")+5:str.find("\RMSD")].translate(None, "\n ")

# the string is now just numbers separated by commas, so split it to a list
# using the ',' deliminator 
list = values.split(',')
```

Now list has:

```
['568.8880019', '-568.2343213', '-568.2343432', '...', '-586.3284921']
```

Answer (score 0):

I had something like this open and forgot to post - a "slightly" different answer that uses `mmap`'d files and `re.finditer`:

This has the advantage of dealing with larger files relatively efficiently as it allows the regex engine to see the file as one long string without it being in memory at once.

```
import mmap
import re

with open('/home/jon/blah.txt') as fin:
    mfin = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    for match in re.finditer(r'\\HF=(.*?)\\RMSD=', mfin, re.DOTALL):
        print match.group(1).translate(None, '\n ').split(',')

# ['-568.8880019', '-568.2343213', '-568.2343432', '...', '-586.3284921']
```